# Why is /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/default returning blank?

Tags: apache, apache2, lamp

I just installed a LAMP stack and when I ran `sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/default`, it was empty, like whatever file it opened doesn't exist. Never had this problem on my last LAMP install. What's going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The files in Apache's `sites-enabled` directory are ordered, which means that the filenames start with a number.  The default site is usually named `000-default` or similar, not just `default`.  Take a look in the directory to see what's there with `ls`, then edit that file with nano.

```
> ls -l /etc/apache2/sites-enabled

    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 26 Nov 14  2013 000-default -> ../sites-available/default

> sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello thank you i get also this issue, as mentionned by Brian Kintz, I did

```
ls -l /etc/apache2/sites-enabled
```

and get line like :

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 26 Nov 14  2013 000-default -> ../sites-available/default
```

I try to edit it :

```
 sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default
```

I have only virtualhost block inside this file.

Thank you